# trying to sort responses from Google Forms answers using Google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to create a project that sorts those who register in my Google form by gender, and saves each registered person on a page in an Excel document (according to the chosen gender, a document for males and a document for females).
I tried to search, and I created a new google spreadsheet to link it to the form and Google scripts, and this code is what I came up with, but it does not work.
Despite adding the code, and giving it the necessary permissions to run, the script does not do anything, although it appears to me that it is executed successfully in the execution logs, but the responses are saved in the usual (normal) way in the spreadsheet.
The code I tried it:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var formResponse = e.values;
  
  var gender = formResponse[2];
  
  var sheetName = '';
  
  switch(gender) {
    case 'male':
      sheetName = 'males';
      break;
    case 'female':
      sheetName = 'females';
      break;
  }

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!targetSheet) {
    targetSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  }
  targetSheet.appendRow(formResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sobj = {male:"Sheet0",female:"Sheet1"};//I used Sheet0 and Sheet1
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(sobj[e.values[2]]);//get the sheet directy
  sh.appendRow(e.values);//append data
}
```

Comment: this does not work.

Comment: It works for me.  I ran it with a form that I already had.  You must be doing something wrong.  How did you test it?

Comment: @ibraheemmohsen, just in case there is any confusion, note that you need to create an "on form submit" installable trigger, and [2] is column C.